Increase the size of iterator on a per element basis / Expand and Map iterator
Im trying to find or implement a method that works on any iterator, which allows me to iterate over all elements and for every element create multiple new elements that then become part of the old iterator. This effectively increases the iterator in size.
First of all, there is already a way to do this, just that is not feasible for the program I'm writing, since this is quite long and tedious and I would to do this very often.
//This is not the actual usecase, just example code
fn main() {
   let numbers: Vec<i32> = vec![10, 20, 30];
   
   //this bit here
   let result_nums: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
   for num in number.iter() {
      result_nums.push(num);
      result_nums.push(num + 1);
      result_nums.push(num + 2);
   }
}

The main operation in this piece of code I need, the code in the for loop, which 'expands' the numbers array into a new array result_nums.
The way I want to write this code is the following:
fn main() {
   let numbers: Vec<i32> = vec![10, 20, 30];

   //this bit
   let result: Vec<i32> = numbers.iter().expand(|x, container| -> {
       container.push(x);
       container.push(x + 1);
       container.push(x + 2);
   }).collect()

   //the iterator will now contain the elements: [10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32]
}

This is the most ergonomic way I could think of. Keep in mind I'm going to be chaining the expand() operations and I won't just collect after every single one, this is just for the sake of the example.
It would really save time and would be way less verbose, since I won't have to keep making temporary arrays with the whole type-signature, aswell as write the entire for loop.
If anyone knows of a crate that can do this or a better, even more ergonomic way of writing these expand operation, then please let me know!

I think you're looking for flat_map(): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=301d7a42724293c6268d15a7f2dc9cb6

That is what im looking for, apparently Im really bad at googling. Thank you for the help!

@user4815162342 Suggested the use of the standard-library method flat_map, which makes this exact implementation possible!
Implementation:
fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<i32> = vec![10, 20, 30];
    let result: Vec<i32> = numbers
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|&x| [x, x + 1, x + 2])
        .collect();
    assert_eq!(result, [10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32])
}

Playground

It's generally considered courteous on StackOverflow to allow the commenter who resolved the issue some time to post their own answer. Also, answers shouldn't consist of (just) links to external sites, they should stand on their own. In this case the code from the playground link should be incorporated in the answer, and optionally followed up by the playground link for ease of testing. (This answer is a possible example, but there are of course many others.)

@user4815162342 I wanted to accept your answer, but It was not listed as an answer, I think? I wasnt quite sure if you were going to send another answer

I was just about to post one (after checking for dups), but you beat me to the punch. :) Don't worry about it, just please edit the answer to include the code, as suggested in the remainder of my comment.

I cant accept my own answer for two days anyway, and I think you deserve the to get the accepted answer since you came up with it. I rarely use Stackoverflow so I generally don't know the proper etiquette.
If youre going to post an answer, I will accept that, if you havent posted one in two days ill accept mine to get this answered

Normally I'd answer, but since you've already posted your answer, there's really no need to. Thanks for being considerate about the etiquette, and have fun on StackOverflow!

I just went ahead and edited your answer to improve markdown formatting; feel free to review.
